# D/InMobiBanner: Ad request successful but no ad served

Tags: android, admob, inmobi

keep on getting integrating inmobi with admob
D/InMobiBanner: Ad request successful but no ad served.

works OK if test mode is turned on for inmobi placement.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if the Ad Server doesn't have an ad for the user then it will return with no-fill in that case you can see this message. On the dashboard, you can find out a number of requests made and number of ads filled.